# Font Awesome: Some icons not showing on mobile (iPhone iOS)

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, font-awesome-5

I've upgraded to the new Font Awesome 5 because I had some trouble displaying some icons (ie Twitter Square and Facebook Square) on mobile devices. By upgrading I hoped to solve the problem, yet it didn't.

I've upgraded to 5 and I've tried a lot to see what could be the problem. Even on JSBin the icon shows up on my computer, but not on my mobile device. I have an iPhone running iOS 11.2.

This is the JSBin link where I tried to test it and reproduce the problem. I think the problem is within the Font Awesome source as I can't narrow it further much down I guess...

https://jsbin.com/zeruxafimi/edit?html,output

This is the code from the jsbin:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Font Awesome Test</title>
        <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is the icon: </p>
        <a href=''><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-3x"></i></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Anyone familiair with Font Awesome and knows how to solve this?
Note: not all icons are not working. The envelope square icon for example works fine.

```
<i class="fas fa-envelope-square fa-3x"></i>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have tried to download the icons to my server and link them directly to see if that solved the problem but unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution myself.

After some investigation I found that the problem only happened on my own iPhone. Other phones with similar OS did not have the problem. Therefore the problem had to be with my device. After some thinking, I remembered that I used Purify on my phone as an Ad-block within Safari. This was the cause of the Twitter-icon not appearing, as it was deleted/stopped from showing up on my device. After deactivating Purify, the icon appeared on my device and the problem is therefore solved!

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I could not figure out what was wrong with my iPhone. Purify has a setting to block custom fonts. For some reason I had this toggled on. Finally, after months of seeing squares everywhere in iOS Safari, I can finally see icons again!

Comment: I'm glad to help! :)